# Kibibtye or Kilobyte to represent 1024 bytes

Tags: terminology

I am working on a project with several older programmer and we were doing up the documentation of the program when I had a heated debate with one of the older programmers regarding the term : `Kilobyte`.

He wanted to stick to the old way of using `Kilobytes` to represent 1024 bytes as he said most programmers understood the term : Kilobyte to represent 1024 bytes.

I wanted the new way of using [`Kibibyte` to represent 1024 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) as we can't forever be stuck in our old ways and this has been updated by the community.

How should I resolve this conflict with him so as to appease both of us  ??

Comment: "this has been updated by the community." Which community? there are lots of places that don't care about Kibibytes. Personally, I agree that Kilo was 10^3 far before it became 2^10, so we should get our own term; but Kibi-, Mebi- and Gibi- are just too awful to take seriously.

Comment: "we can't forever be stuck in our old ways". Oh, yes you can.

Comment: @downvoters please explain ?? I feel this is a reasonable question

Comment: @Computernerd This sounds like a "rant" in that you're complaining about someone else's opinion and trying to get people to agree with your own, as opposed to asking the question in good faith.  It seems like one of those things that "most" people "just don't care about."  Personally, I've never even heard of this debate before.

Comment: @Javier not in computing it wasn't :) Computing mathematics has always been binary after all. It's a relatively recent phenomenon introduced by harddisk manufacterers to market products as billions of bytes and call that gigabytes in order to to get a seemingly higher number in their catalogues.

Answer (score 8):

Use Kilobyte as it's the generally accepted term of art. Kibibyte is a [hypercorrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection) unless it's somehow critically important to the functioning of the application. Software documentation should focus on clarity. This includes adhering to accepted conventions.

Comment: Definitely agree.  It's one of those trivial details that's not nearly as important as consistency.  The "wrong" way is used so mainstream that it effectively is correct now.

Comment: Disagree. This 'convention' currently causes only problems and no profit. Storage units have their capacity measured in 1000's, eg 128 GB often reported by software as 119G(i)B which look like fraud (but its not). How long should 60 Mb file transferred through 1 MB/s link? 60 s is wrong answer. And so on...

Comment: @Vovanium In that case it would be "critically important to the functioning of the application", yes?

Comment: @WorldEngineer It is unclear, what mean 'critical' in general. Is it referred to operator confusion, application crash, hardware fault, money loss or someone's death? I do not see though any reason for ambigouos term to live.

Comment: @Vovanium In the case of embedded systems, safety criticality would be a concern and therefore the use of the less popular term would be justified. If you were the lead architect writing out the specs, then this would be an entirely different answer. If you are a junior programmer, then it will only serve to alienate you from your colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

Just abbreviate it to `KiB`, that way it's somewhat ambiguous as to whether you mean "Kilobyte" or "Kibibyte".

`KiB` does technically mean "Kibibyte", so, if you go with that, you may win without the other party knowing.

Realistically though, hardly anyone uses the term "Kibibyte", and it would cause more confusion to introduce it instead of using "Kilobyte".

Comment: I personally don't use the full word (kibibyte) EVER, but *always* write it a KiB because (a) is clerarer what I mean (b) I like that the uppercase K is correct (as kilobyte would be kB and not KB)